# Concat and wrap in anonymous function multiple js files (build process)

Tags: javascript, build-process, gulp

I'm building a pretty big script in javascript and I wrap it in an anonymous function so it won't be in the global outer space.
This should be implemented on multiple sites as a service that don't need any public api for the time being (and if and when it will be needed i'll just expose the functions it want).

This is a sample of my one huge js file:

```
"use strict";

(function() {
    var MyApp = {};

    /************************************************************
     * MyApp helpers
     ************************************************************/
    MyApp.Helpers = {};

    /**
     * Generate something
     */
    MyApp.Helpers.someFunc = function() {
    }

    /************************************************************
     * MyApp Widget
     ************************************************************/
    MyApp.Widget = function() {};

    /**
     * Create / update widget's dom element
     */
    MyApp.Widget.prototype.build = function() {
        this.driver.build();
    };

    /************************************************************
     * Widget Drivers
     ************************************************************/
    MyApp.Widget.Drivers = {};

    /************************************************************
     * Some Driver
     ************************************************************/
    MyApp.Widget.Drivers.SomeDriver = function(widget) {
        this.widget = widget;
    }

    /************************************************************
     * Run app
     ************************************************************/
    // Fire in the hole!
    MyApp.App.init();
})();
```

I want to break it up to multiple files under multiple directories and build it in one gulp function.

As of now this the js-specific gulp task:

```
var jsFiles = [
    'src/js/vendor/*.js', // polyfills and other non-project-specific plugins
    'src/js/MyApp.js' // my huge js file
];

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(jsFiles)
        .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});
```

So.. does that even make sense or I'm just doing it wrong? and if my question is logical, how can I make it happen?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello! Not sure I understand the problem, but did you try the bundle-js npm package? It allows you to include js files onto one another when creating the bundle. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bundle-js